# Search and get row from large single string

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, string

Hi I have single large string and i need to search set of string from this string and get that row create a data frame with this rows.
large String:
[image]

---

This is democracy’s day.

A day of history and hope.

Of renewal and resolve.

Through a crucible for the ages America has been tested anew and America has risen to the challenge.

Today, we celebrate the triumph not of a candidate, but of a cause, the cause of democracy.

The will of the people has been heard and the will of the people has been heeded.

We have learned again that democracy is precious.

---

Now i want to search few set of strings from above.
and my final output dataframe should look like below

[image]

---

**Searching string**
democracy’s day
America has been tested
celebrate the triumph
democracy is precious

---

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post data as text, not images. That makes it possible to cut & paste it to generate a solution.

Comment: Show us the code you have written, even if it is not yet working properly. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a regex out of your search strings and compare them for a match against the `Large String` column using [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html). Where there's a match, the match string will be the value in the `Searching String` column, otherwise it will be null. The dataframe can then be filtered on the `Searching String` value being not null:

```py
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Large String': ["This is democracy's day.", "A day of history and hope.","Of renewal and resolve.","Through a crucible for the ages America has been tested anew and America has risen to the challenge.","Today, we celebrate the triumph not of a candidate, but of a cause, the cause of democracy.","The will of the people has been heard and the will of the people has been heeded.","We have learned again that democracy is precious."] })

search_strings = ["democracy's day", "America has been tested", "celebrate the triumph", "democracy is precious"]

regex = '|'.join(map(re.escape, search_strings))

df['Searching String'] = df['Large String'].str.extract(f'({regex})')

df = df[~df['Searching String'].isna()]

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                                        Large String         Searching String
0                           This is democracy's day.          democracy's day
3  Through a crucible for the ages America has be...  America has been tested
4  Today, we celebrate the triumph not of a candi...    celebrate the triumph
6  We have learned again that democracy is precious.    democracy is precious
```

Note:

- we use `re.escape` on the search strings in case they contain special characters for regex e.g. `.` or `(` etc.
- if one of the search strings is a subset of another, the list should be sorted by order of decreasing length to ensure the longer matches are captured